# How to traverse up the directory structure and kick off mvn build in vimscript?

Tags: maven, vim

I'm a new vim user who is looking for a little help with a script that would allow me to call mvn build.

Currently I map this as follows

```
map <F3> :! mvn build<CR>
```

but because this tries to do the build in my current working directory (currently java development so I'm deep in a package under src usually)

How might I go up the directory structure so this mvn build command works correctly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vimscript function [`finddir()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#finddir%28%29) can be used to find the `src` directory.  The syntax used in its second argument (`path`) has some [augmentations to basic path specification](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching), one of which is the ability to specify an upward search using the `;`:

```
let src_dir = finddir('src', ';')
```

This will find the src directory if it's above the current directory.

To do a build in this directory, you can run

```
exec '!cd' shellescape(src_dir) '&& mvn build'
```

I don't think this will work under windows.  In that case, I think you'd want to change directory temporarily using vim's [`cd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3acd) command, run the command, and then change back using [`:cd -`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3acd-).

You can combine those commands into a function

```
function! RunMavenInSrcDir()
    let src_dir = finddir('src', ';')
    exec 'cd' fnameescape(src_dir)
    !mvn build
    cd -
endfunction
```

Running this function will have the side effect of clobbering vim's *previous current directory*: in other words, doing `:cd -` afterwards won't necessarily change to the same directory it would have before.

You can arrange to have the function invoked by a mapping with

```
map <F3> :call RunMavenInSrcDir()<CR>
```

or by a command with

```
command! RunMavenInSrcDir call RunMavenInSrcDir()
```

Comment: excellent - if I want to cd up 1 more directory (1 up from src that is) - how might I modify that function? thank you!

Comment: @JimmyBond: you can `let src_dir = fnamemodify(src_dir, ':p:h')` just after the first `let`.

Comment: nevermind - it looks like a simple exec 'cd ..' right after the cd into src works! thanks again!

Comment: @JimmyBond: Sure, that works except that a subsequent `cd -` will just take you back to the `src` dir rather than returning you to the directory you were originally in.  That might not matter for you though.

Comment: Excellent find- fixed this using the let statement in your comment :) (thanks again for all the help)

Comment: if I wanted to set my ctags = this same location + "/ctags" what would this look like inside this same function?

Comment: @intuited so a simple !tags = ./tags;,./TAGS; in my .vimrc ?